# Update an invoice's related project field via API

Tags: activecollab

This relates to Active Collab's API.

When updating an invoice (using `PUT` method) I see how I can update the `project_id` value, and this is working.

However, I would like to be able to associate an invoice with a project. I see that is done via the `related_project_ids` field. How do I update this field using the API?

Answer (score 0):

Active Collab 5.9.22 joins value of invoice's `project_id` field with all related projects (via related time records and expenses) in one list of projects. What this means that project that you set by sending a PUT request will be listed as invoice's project, even when there are extra project loaded from related time records and expenses.

In order for you Active Collab to behave like that, you need to run Active Collab 5.9.22 or newer.

Regarding update of `related_project_ids`, that value can't be changed via API. It is automatically prepared based on time records and expenses that were used to create an invoice.